# Logging server status

Tags: node.js, sails.js, log4js-node

I am currently adding logs in my application using log4js (not the default sails logger). I'd like to be able to keep track of the server status : when it's up and down. Where should I put the logs to be able to know when the server is down?

Thanks for bringing me out of darkness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test it, but if you want to write a log when the server is shutting down you could try to use [the `exit` event of the `process` object](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_event_exit)

```
var log4js = require('log4js');
process.on('exit', function(code) {
  var logger = log4js.getLogger();
  logger.info("End of the process");
});
```